# Can't send a request, OpenSSL key and cert error

Tags: python, openssl

I have different error output for Linux and Windows (both use python 3.7.3 and PyOpenSSL 19.0).

```py
response = s.post(url=my_url,
                 data=json.dumps(data.__dict__), 
                 timeout=15,
                 headers={'accept': 'application/json', 'content-type':'application/json'}, 
                 cert=(str(Path(__file__).parents[1]) + "/my_key.key",str(Path(__file__).parents[1]) + "/my_cert.crt"),
                 verify=False)
```

And I've installed `OpenSSL` and wrappers for Python on both systems.

On Windows:
`OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines', 'get_name', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'use_certificate_chain_file', 'PEM lib')]`

On Linux 
`[('PEM routines', 'get_name', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib')]`

And I'm sure that cert and key are OK, because I've tried a `curl` request.

What causes this error?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your certificate and key files are in the incorrect format.  From the error, it looks like it wants a the certificate and key in the PEM format. My guess is that your certificate and key are in DER format.  Try converting the files from DER to PEM. See https://serverfault.com/questions/254627/how-do-i-convert-a-cer-certificate-to-pem

Comment: @ShanePowell, you are right. Works fine with PEM, thank you. Could you write is an answer and I will accept it as solved problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your certificate and key files are in the incorrect format. From the error, it looks like it wants a the certificate and key in the PEM format.

My guess is that your certificate and key are in DER format. Try converting the files from DER to PEM.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/254627/how-do-i-convert-a-cer-certificate-to-pem as a example of how to convert CER to PEM format.